# Unable to play audio in firebase storage sent from android app

Tags: android, firebase, audio, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to upload audio from my android app and then download and play in my app.
The audio file gets uploaded but when I play it from firebase storage,it comes in a video format like image below and does not play the audio.
I am also setting metadata as audio/mp3 for it.

I tried to search about the same in firebase documentation and google but could not get my issue resolved.

[image: video format]

```
Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(fileName));
 //filename is audio stored in my phone's local storage.

StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setContentType("audio/mp3")
            .build();

// Upload the file and metadata


 UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.child("audio/audio.mp3").putFile(file, metadata);

uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
    }
}).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
    }
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Handle successful uploads on complete
        // ...
        Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
        while(!uri.isComplete());
        Uri url = uri.getResult();

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Success, download URL " +
                url.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return storageReference.getDownloadUrl();

    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();

        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

I want the audio to be saved properly in firebase storage and then stream it in my app.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem could have been caused by **MediaRecorder**. I have figured out that the output format should be set to **AAC**. Then the browser will be able to play it. I experienced this problem when I was trying to use React JS to play audio captured by MediaRecorder in Android, and I tried various formats (.3gp, .mp4, .wav), but this is the only one that worked. I suspect there are other ones, too.

So:

```
mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
        .setContentType("audio/mpeg")
        .build();

uploadTask = storageRef.child("audio/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file,metadata);
```

Comment: I tried the above code but the issue remains the same.